# Javascript Fetch not working on mobile devices

Tags: javascript, html, fetch-api

I am trying to display content from json online on my HTML. It works fine on my laptop but on my phone browser (chrome) and my friends (opera) it doesn't work. I've checked the [compatibility](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/json) with it and it should be fine?

Heres my HTML that I'm using:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="15" >
        <title>Alton Towers Predicted Queue Times</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <script>
        fetch("https://queue-times.com/parks/1/queue_times.json")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {document.querySelector("#name").innerText = data.lands[0].rides[0].name});

    </script>

        <h3><span id="name"></span></h3>

    </body>
</html>
```

Any idea why this works on my laptop but not my phone?

Comment: Have you tried running your snippet in the question? And how is it not working on the browsers? I see a blank screen when running your script.

Comment: By "Not working" I mean it's a blank screen. After more tests this is what I've found:
Chrome (PC), works - Firefox (PC), doesn't work, Safari (iOS), doesn't work - Chrome (Android), doesn't; work.

Comment: Oh, i think I know why it's not working. I've got a cors bypasser extension on my laptop. Thats why it works on there but not anywhere else.

Comment: Understood. Since you do not have access to the code of the API you are requesting, you will need to insert a proxy between your request and the target and assign the appropriate CORS headers for your proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the problem is a CORS issue. Since this is a third-party site that you do not have access to, you will need to implement a small server-side code that will receive a request, send its equivalent to the actual target, receive the target's response and send that back to the browser. For your small server-side code, that will act as a proxy you can easily set the appropriate CORS headers so you will be able to perform the requests.

Comment: I have used a third party cors proxy and added the appropriate headers. It works fine on my laptop but when I look at the console from my phone (which doesn't work) I get this error "(index):9 GET https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://queue-times.com/parks/1/queue_times.json 403 (Forbidden)". This error only shows when requesting the site from my phone.

Comment: @ThomasKeig how you was able to view console on your phone?